# JS functions in GWT

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.5

how use this simple js functions in GWT? (picture animation script for example)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cSpeed=4;
var cWidth=64;
var cHeight=64;
var cTotalFrames=8;
var cFrameWidth=64;
var cImageSrc='images/sprites.gif';

var cImageTimeout=false;
var cIndex=0;
var cXpos=0;
var cPreloaderTimeout=false;
var SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES=0;

function startAnimation(){

    document.getElementById('loaderImage').style.backgroundImage='url('+cImageSrc+')';
    document.getElementById('loaderImage').style.width=cWidth+'px';
    document.getElementById('loaderImage').style.height=cHeight+'px';

    //FPS = Math.round(100/(maxSpeed+2-speed));
    FPS = Math.round(100/cSpeed);
    SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES = 1 / FPS;

    cPreloaderTimeout=setTimeout('continueAnimation()', SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES/1000);

}

function continueAnimation(){

    cXpos += cFrameWidth;
    //increase the index so we know which frame of our animation we are currently on
    cIndex += 1;

    //if our cIndex is higher than our total number of frames, we're at the end and should restart
    if (cIndex >= cTotalFrames) {
        cXpos =0;
        cIndex=0;
    }

    if(document.getElementById('loaderImage'))
        document.getElementById('loaderImage').style.backgroundPosition=(-cXpos)+'px 0';

    cPreloaderTimeout=setTimeout('continueAnimation()', SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES*1000);
}

function stopAnimation(){//stops animation
    clearTimeout(cPreloaderTimeout);
    cPreloaderTimeout=false;
}

function imageLoader(s, fun)//Pre-loads the sprites image
{
    clearTimeout(cImageTimeout);
    cImageTimeout=0;
    genImage = new Image();
    genImage.onload=function (){cImageTimeout=setTimeout(fun, 0)};
    genImage.onerror=new Function('alert(\'Could not load the image\')');
    genImage.src=s;
}

//The following code starts the animation
new imageLoader(cImageSrc, 'startAnimation()');
```

tried wrapping

```
    public static native void anim()
/*-{
   js here
}-*/;
```

but Uncaught ReferenceError: startAnimation is not defined

i've seen 
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html
but didn't find examples for js functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSNI:

**Method 1:** if you ALWAYS call imageLoader with `fun = 'startAnimation()'`, i mean, you always use imageLoader this way: `imageLoader(s, 'startAnimation()');`

```
class YourMethods
{
    public static native void imageLoader(String s) /*-{
    imageLoader(s, 'startAnimation()');
    }-*/;
}
```

You can call this method like this:

```
YourMethods::imageLoader(s);
```

**Method 2:** if you `fun` parameter change (is not always `'startAnimation()'`), BUT ALWAYS IS A TYPE STRING

```
class YourMethods
{
    public static native void imageLoader(String s, String fun) /*-{
    imageLoader(s, fun);
    }-*/;
}
```

In this case: you define second parameter like "javascript name of function", and call it this way:

```
YourMethods::imageLoader(s, "startAnimation()");
```

And GWT understand fun parameter like name of javascript function, and type string

**Method 3:** convert ALL your javascript code to GWT

Comment: but "fun" is a function in args here. js function is not a real java type :/
and in general, where to find different examples of use a native js in gwt? 
in network are not very many such examples

Comment: it ended up that i just put js code in html and call it from the application. but the task was to add it to the page dynamically. I am afraid that the answer to the question of how to generate and use native js in gwt directly from the app, we have not received. although I'll mark your answer as correct, it gives reason to think

Answer (score 1):

You need to add $wnd to access JavaScript which is included directly in your HTML host page.

```
$wnd.startAnimation();
```